# Changing the subscription status of a Mobile Push contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, ios, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I'm currently testing the implementation of the Mobile Push SDK in an app of client.

Due to improper iOS certification configuration (development instead of production) and a number send attempts I ended up with an opted-out status and "ServiceFeedback" opt-out method on my testing device.

Is there any way of reversing the opt-out or changing the subscription status in Mobile Push?

The only option that I can come up with right now is to delete the contact with the new deletion features, but I realistically I can't expect the client to wait 14 days for the contact to be deleted and testing to be resumed after that.

Comment: where are you seeing the ServiceFeedback opt-out  for the contact?

Comment: @PraveenKumarBandi, in the contact membership data as seen [here](https://i.imgur.com/whdpP6d.png).

I've found a workaround and just created a new user on this device in the end which allowed me to continue testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the status field in the mobile push demographics under the Attributes tab in All contacts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@rufenstein you *should* be able to trigger a registration update from your app to clear that feedback value. The easiest way is to set a tag.

Note: it may take a few minutes for the registration to process and update that contact.